# Confused on approach to Griffiths solution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hamiltonian, eigenvalue, time-evolution

I am trying to work through some old questions to brush up on my QM, and have a solutions manual for Griffiths version 2. I am looking at a question ($3.37$) where you have a three level system and are trying to figure out the time evolution of a given state. The Hamiltonian matrix is shown as,

$H= \begin{pmatrix} a & 0 & b\\0 & c & 0\\b & 0 & a\end{pmatrix}$

with eigenvectors of $|s_1\rangle=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$,
$|s_2\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$, and
$|s_3\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$

The first question asks to use time evolution for $|s(0)\rangle=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$, and the solution uses $|s_1\rangle$, which makes sense to me, but the second question asks for,
$|s(0)\rangle=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$, and it uses $|s_2\rangle+|s_3\rangle$ and I don't know where that comes from. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I didn't want to include too many details as to not give away the solution.

Comment: There should be a minus sign, tho (and a factor of $\sqrt{2}$ is missing). In other words: A *straightforward* computation yields $ \sqrt 2|s(0)\rangle= |s_1\rangle -  |s_2\rangle$. So either you or the book (or both) have confused something.

Comment: Yes I think you're right. Maybe it's a typo in the book?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I wasn't sure if I was losing my mind or something.